# Multiple text lines in MS Excel rows by default

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office-2019

I have an excel sheet which I use to write notes. I want either of the two things.

1. All rows to be multi-line (ideally 2 lines high) so if the content doesn't fit it one row, it automatically wraps to the next line
2. All rows to be single line except if the content doesn't fit in one row, it automatically wraps to the next line. The only difference is that this will only affect the row which has longer content, instead of all the rows.

Note: I don't want to press `Alt`+`Enter` or do anything manually each time. It should happen automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the area you want to be multi-lined.

Then click wrap text.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, worked. Is it possible to wrap the whole sheet all the time without having to click that button?

Comment: @CodePanda you can select the whole sheet using CTRL+A and then click the button

Comment: The only way to have it more automated than @PeterH's suggestion of setting it for a whole sheet at a time, is to edit the default blank template for Excel. Then all your future new workbooks will at least have this set. See here https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2017/aug/modify-excel-default-blank-workbook.html

Comment: And if you really don't like clicking that button, hit ALT, H, W (in sequence not together).

Answer (score 0):

I had to dig this out of the Wayback Machine, as the original tech site (http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Excel/microsoft.public.excel.setup/2004-06/0118.html) was down. Thought it worth reposting. Credit Gord Dibben.

```
From: Gord Dibben (gorddibbATshawDOTca)
Date: 06/17/04 
In reply to: L Schmandt: "how to default all cells to wrap text?" 
Date: Thu, 17 Jun 2004 08:15:03 -0700
```

> Hit CRTL + A to select all cells. Format>Alignment>Wrap Text. To make
> this the default for all new workbooks and sheets.... Open a new
> workbook. Customize as you wish. File>Save As Type: scroll down to
> Excel Template(*.XLT) and select. Name your workbook "BOOK"(no
> quotes). Excel will add the .XLT to save as BOOK.XLT. Store this
> workbook in the XLSTART folder usually located at........
> C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application
> Data\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART This will be the default workbook for
> File>New>Workbook. You can also open a new workbook and delete all but
> one sheet. Customize as you wish then save this as SHEET.XLT in
> XLSTART folder also. It now becomes the default Insert>Sheet. More can
> be found on this in Help under "templates"(no quotes). Gord Dibben
> Excel MVP

Comment: Updated path under Windows 10 `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART`